# How I can create table by splitting all H1 followed by text until next H1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have data field contain following data

```
<h1> title1 </h1> some text 1 <h1> title2 </h1> some text 2 <h1> title3 </h1> some text 3
```

I want to create table  of element which will contain

```
<h1> title1 </h1> some text 1<br>
<h1> title2 </h1> some text 2 <br>
<h1> title3 </h1> some text 3
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Why you have that quote in the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have a native string split function, though you still can use substring_index to do basic or multiple splits.

```
select substring_index(yourCol, '<''h1>', 2) from yourTab ...
```

And you might be end up with doing several times.

The quickest way is to export your table, and use text editor to replace <'h1> with new line

And import back the text (as CSV) into a temporary table, you need some basic DBA skills to do that.

Good luck

Comment: Sorry but all I have h1 tag followed by text. I want to break by consecutive H1. Please ignore  '  character

Comment: Please update your question: 1 what is the actual raw text look like, you can  add 4 space in front of your text to look real. 2 what do you want as a result